# Jetty HTTP/2: How to set client session timeout?

Tags: jetty, http2

I'm trying to create one session and reuse it for every request.
The problem is if I try to send a request after 30 seconds after the session was createad, I get:

```
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at  org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Session$ControlEntry.succeeded
(HTTP2Session.java:1224) ~[http2-common-9.4.0.v20161208.jar:9.4.0.v20161208]
```

I tried like this

```
   SSLSessionContext clientSessionContext = sslContextFactory.getSslContext().getClientSessionContext();
  clientSessionContext.setSessionTimeout(60000);
```

but it doesen't seems to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `HttpClient`, the client idle timeout can be set with `HttpClient.setIdleTimeout(long)`.

If you are using the low-level `HTTP2Client`, the client idle timeout can be set with `HTTP2Client.setIdleTimeout(long)`.

Both will control the connection/session idle timeout, which is apparently what you want. A negative value will disable the idle timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried as follows
            HTTP2Client client = new HTTP2Client();
            client.setIdleTimeout(-1);

But my session is closed after 30 seconds

Comment: If the client has its idle timeout disabled, the session could still be closed by the server. If you control the server, you have to call `ServerConnector.setIdleTimeout(long)`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
It worked!
I set the timeout on server side and everything look ok.